# What could be wrong with my usb 3.0 chain?

Tags: usb

I moved my computer to another room. To accomplish this, I used 3x3m + 1m usb3 extension cables and 4xusb3 hubs all daisy chained together so it goes like

```
computer -> 3m cable -> hub -> 3m cable -> hub -> 3m cable -> hub -> 1m cable -> hub
```

I've also powered the second and the last hub with 2A external adapters to combat voltage drop, its at ~5.1V at the powered hubs and ~4.8 at the unpowered ones.

Anyways, the whole chain works at USB 3.0 speeds most of the time but after a few hours, it just stops. Doesn't fall back to 2.0, all the hubs/devices are still powered but its just as if the whole chain is disconnected. All the devices are also missing from device manager.

The only way it comes back is when I either restart the computer or wait ~20 min after unplugging before I replug.

I've tried different usb3 ports and after it goes down in one of them, the chain doesn't work in any of them wheras any other device I plug in there works fine.

Its stable if I plug the chain into a 2.0 port (also works after it goes down in 3.0 port) but I bought usb3 parts for a reason...

Its also stable if the hubs don't have extension cables between them. (doesn't work after it goes down)

So, anybody got a clue what could be wrong with this setup?

relevant specs:

Hubs and cables - the cheapest noname items you can order online from china

asus p9x79, windows 7

currently only have usb2 keyboard and mouse connected to the last hub

Comment: Get a RaspPi, install [usbip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net) on both RaspPi (server) and your PC (client), connect RaspPi via LAN or WLAN to your main computer, and you have a reliable long-distance USB connection. Will work for keyboard and mouse, won't work for USB alternate mode (monitors etc.).

Answer (score 2):

> What could be wrong with my usb 3.0 chain?
>
> Hubs and cables - the cheapest noname items you can order online from
>   china

Yes, this is what is wrong.

To begin, the USB standard discourages the use of "extender cables", they have no specification/certification rules, and therefore can't be trusted. The main reason is that an extender would have an additional mating pair of connectors, and connectors are the weakest link in maintaining the quality of high-speed transmission line.

Second, reputable certified USB 3.0 cables are no more than 2-m long. These are the cables used in all USB-3 evaluation and certification technologies. And if one connector is of u-USB type, the cables are just 1-m long. There is a reason for that, it is fairly difficult and expensive to make long cables that meet requirements for differential insertion loss (which mainly determines the signal eye quality). Of course there could be exceptions, but it is highly unlikely. So the quality of your 3-m extender is likely on the verge of functional margins, and, as hub/chip temperature rises over time (again the cheap Chinese hub ICs), some links go off.

Third, if some USB 3.0 link goes down as result of unstable and non-recoverable transmission, the USB 2.0 mode link, which runs in parallel to USB 3.0 link should remain functional. I am afraid the Windows 7 software driver, however, treats the non-recoverable USB 3.0 link as total port failure, and disables both USB2 and USB3 functions. It might be different on newer xCHI controllers though.

What is the solution for using USB 3.0 at >10m distance - is another question. There are optical-fiber solutions by Corning, there are active extender cables with USB 3.0 repeaters every 4m. Unfortunately, these solutions come at certain cost.

Answer (score 0):

Too many low-quality elements in your chain. It would only take one glitch
for the driver to give up on your device.

I don't understand why you have gone to this complicated setup,
when you could have done it all with one active extension cable
and have a much more stable configuration.
Such cables can run even to 15m
([example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06Y29FJSQ) at $69.99),
although 10m might be enough
([example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B076C6PDNH) at $32.95).

Comment: Why? Mostly because the whole lot cost me $10

Comment: You might be able to find cheaper extension cables - I haven't searched that. In general, you get what you pay for,

Comment: I looked pretty thoroughly, ~$30 was the cheapest I found. That is excluding usb repeater assembled pcbs which with the special cable would have cost around as much as the hubs+cables but would still have required a few hours of manual labor to put together. Also i don't think "because its cheap" is really an answer, I've seen the same hub models for sale in physical stores over here under various brand names for $20 and I'm sure I paid at least 50% premium for them even ordering from china. The true cost of this type of electronics is nearly nothing these days anyway.